# Prepare Statement doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Do you know what could be the problem? The query is working fine. I tried it in PHPMyAdmin and it returned everything I expected except  `taskTime` which isn't empty. It gives the correct number:

[image]

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($SQLhost, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $SQLdatabase);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Account.accountEmail, Account.accountUsername,Task.taskName,Task.taskDescription,Task.taskTime FROM Account INNER JOIN Task ON Task.accountId=Account.accountId WHERE taskId=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $taskId);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($accountEmail,$accountUsername,$taskName,$taskDesc,$taskTime);

echo("Account Email: " . $accountEmail . " | Account Username: " .$accountUsername . " | Task Name: " . $taskName . " | Task Desc: " . $taskDesc . " | Task Time: " . $time . " | Task Id: " . $taskId);
```

Comment: 1) always check the return value of every API call. 2) verify that your input is correct (e.g.: `echo $taskId`)

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking return values? mysqli will return false by default on failure, e.g. `if (!$stmt) { die (mysqli_error())}` will tell you a lot more than simply assuming everything should work perfectly.

Comment: taskId is fine I get the value from the another function.

Comment: The mistake was because I missed that: $stmt->fetch()...

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($SQLhost, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $SQLdatabase) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli));


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Account.accountEmail, Account.accountUsername,Task.taskName,Task.taskDescription,Task.taskTime FROM Account INNER JOIN Task ON Task.accountId=Account.accountId WHERE taskId=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $taskId);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($accountEmail,$accountUsername,$taskName,$taskDesc,$taskTime);
$stmt->fetch();
```